# How do I send email over SMTP with SSL using Java client?

Tags: java, security, ssl, ssl-certificate

I need to send email over smtp with ssl using java client. I'm not sure how to do that.

1. If I have my server certificate installed on my Windows machine, how do I use it?
2. If I want it to work on a non-Windows machine, do I need to get the certificates in a different way?

BTW: If the SMTP server that I use is using SSL, can I be sure that it will send the mail to the recipient using SSL?

Comment: I prefer not to use javamail, only the java 1.6 api

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip115.html), which details using JavaMail with JSSE (the secure socket extension) and certificate installation.

If you don't want to use JavaMail, you can implement the SMTP protocol yourself over TCP sockets. [See here](http://cr.yp.to/smtp/client.html). But you'll be reimplementing a lot of work which at first sight seems trivial, but will have numerous edge cases and complexities. I would strongly recommend using the APIs for the job.

Comment: I prefer not to use javamail, only the java 1.6 api

Answer (score 0):

1. To simply act as a client to an SSL server you do not need your own certificate.
2. It's no different on non-Windows machines, especially when using Java.

The one thing you may have to do is to [tell your Java client to trust](http://blog.spikesource.com/java_certificate_import.htm) the server's certificate.

Your SSL connection to the SMTP server is puerly point-to-point. There's absolutely no guarantee that it will connect to other clients and servers over SSL (unless you control the server).

Comment: I know that the client do not need its own certificate, it needs the server certificate. I was not sure how to get the server certificate in java code, and configure the SMTP/SSL to use the server certificate to open the SSL connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MailReporter also. 
It supports SSL and TLS! 
http://magithou.com/tips-a-tricks/42-setup-e-mail-accounts/81-ssl-support.htm

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you in setting up the server certificate to be trusted by your java client code.

```
STORE=/path/to/JRE/cacerts
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore $STORE -storepass changeit -noprompt -file mymailserver.pem -alias mymailserver
```

Please use backslashes instead of above forwards slashes (windows guys have confused themselves in path identifiers LOL).

Reference:
http://vafer.org/blog/20061010073725/